# Support of JSON datatype in.NET with Oracle 23c

Tags: json, .net, oracle, .net-core, odp.net

I am working with Oracle 23c as the database for my .NET core application.

My objective is to save and retrieve complex models created in the frontend as a JSON in the database, using the new JSON data type introduced by Oracle.

While I am able to save the JSON data using the OracleDbType.JSON property newly introduced, I am unable to get the data in a JSON format from my stored procedure.

I am using an OUT variable of type REFCURSOR to get the data set that includes a combination of string & JSON fields. However, when I am getting the result the JSON value is getting stringified when I am trying to read it from the dataset.

Any solution regarding how to get the JSON value from database in .NET side, without it getting stringified? #Oracle #dotnet

Tried using DbType.JSON as an OUT parameter just to receive JSON field instead of a REFCURSOR. but that didnt work as well.